# Actually use Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I have got the basics of AD B2C. I have a login page and that kind of thing, but now I want to be able to use it after sign up/sign in.
Here are my main questions:

1. How can I get user data in my website after sign up? Is there an API?
2. Can I associate user data on my website with a user's account?
3. Do I at all need a server-side programming language, or can I just use vanilla JavaScript?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sample should guide you

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/quickstart-web-app-dotnet

1. you get user data from token received from AADB2C and you can call MSGraph Apis
2. Yes, you can add a foreign key in your database which will point to user id in AADB2C to achieve this.
3. Server side would be more appropriate but depends on your use cases.

Comment: This answer would be great, if only I had access to a GUI to use Visual Studio with. Is there a dotnet CLI option for this?

Comment: Visual Studio is a Gui based solution,  you can download Visual studio community. Is that your question?

Comment: Not quite, I'm saying I don't have access to a GUI, only the command-line, so I was wondering if I can do this using the dotnet CLI,

Comment: You can but it will require more setup. You can find more samples here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/